# The basis theorem statement

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

According to the Basis theorem "Let $V$ be a $p$-dimensional vector space, $p \geq 1$. Any linearly independent set of exactly $p$ elements in $V$ is automatically a basis for $V $. Any set of exactly $p$ elements that spans $V$ is automatically a basis for $V$ ."

Now, let us consider the set of three vectors $\{(1, 0, 3), (0, 1, 2), (1, 1, 5)\}$. These vectors span ${\mathbb R}^ 3$, but they do not form the basis of the vector space ${\mathbb R}^ 3$ because the third vector is the sum of the first two vectors. So, isn't the second sentence of the basis theorem "Any set of exactly $p$ elements that spans $V$ is automatically a basis for $V$." false or contradicting?

Comment: Is it the sum of the first two vectors?

Comment: What makes you think those three vectors span $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: General hint, for future reference: When you find a counterexample to a standard theorem that means you've made an error somewhere.

Comment: Do not change your original question, because then the answers get pointless.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the first two vectors is $(1,1,5)$, and not $(0,1,5)$. So they do form a basis. In fact,
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 3 \cr 0 & 1 & 2 \cr 0 & 1 & 5\end{pmatrix}=3,
$$
which is non-zero in the real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try and express $(0,0,1)$ as a linear combination of those three vectors.

You’ll soon discover you can’t.

A linearly dependent set with three vectors cannot span a three-dimensional vector space. That set spans a two-dimensional subspace.

The theorem you quote is correctly stated. A spanning set consisting of $p$ vectors in a $p$-dimensional vector space is a basis.

From every spanning set you can extract a basis: if your set is not a basis, you'd find a basis of $V$ with less elements than $p$. The statement “if a set of $p$ elements is a spanning set of a $p$-dimensional vector space, then it is a basis” is correct.

Answer (score -1):

This might clarify things up:

> If you had two vectors, say they are $v_1$ and $v_2$ which are linearly dependent (i.e. $v_1=3v_2$). Then, the $dim(span(\lbrace v_1, v_2 \rbrace))$ does not have to necessarily equal two. However, if you had two vectors, $v_1$ and $v_2$ which are linearly independent. Then, the $dim(span(\lbrace v_1, v_2 \rbrace))=2$. The dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3=3$, because the $dim(span( \lbrace (1, 0, 0) , (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1) \rbrace))=3$ as there are three vectors (independent) and we know that the $span( \lbrace (1, 0, 0) , (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1) \rbrace)=\mathbb{R}^3$.

The statement "any set of exactly p elements that spans V is automatically a basis for V." for all sets of vectors whether linearly dependent or independent" is wrong.

> For it to be correct, the statement would need to be the following: "any set of vectors with exactly p elements that spans V is automatically a basis for V if the p vectors are independent."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But generalizing the statement "Any set of exactly p elements that spans V is automatically a basis for V." for all sets of vectors whether linearly dependent or independent wrong or incorrect to say? Pls clarify

Comment: However, your statement isn't false or contradicting in this context (your example works coincidentally) because your vectors are not independent. However, the statement does not hold true for all cases.

Comment: Note, if you have r many vectors (independent or not) that span $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then, you know that the dimension of the span of these vectors is $3$. If L and R and sets of vectors, and the span(L) is a subset of the span(R), then the $dim(span(L))\leq dim(span(R))$.

Comment: Good luck. I hope this answered your question.

Comment: W.G. thanks a lot for the help

Comment: ??? You're leaving out the hypothesis about the dimension. The statement "If $V$ has dimension $p$ then any set of $p$ vectors that spans $V$ is automatically a basis for $V$"  is true.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I must have misinterpreted the question. If those vectors span $R^3$ and they are dependent which they obviously are, then this example is a counterexample to that statement. A basis is defined to be linearly independent.

Comment: Also, those vectors do not span $R^3$. Here is an explanation why: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~moose/240S2013/slides7-18.pdf. You solve it the same way as this site and get 3x+2y-z=0 for these vectors, which is a plane, not $R^3$.

Comment: "If those vectors span R3R3 and they are dependent which they obviously are, then this example is a counterexample to that statement." Right. And since that statement is true it _follows_ that those three vectors do not span $\Bbb R^3$.